# Batch list open windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a windows batch file that will print and execute a command if a window is open on the system. I can do this with a process but this is not the effect i want. I want to know if a window is open if so then print open if not do nothing, If there is a way that i can do this please let me know. Better description is when you open taskmanager and the first tab shows open windows. I just want a list of these windows and then from there just search for a program such as googlechrome.exe

Thank you all in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see which executables are running from the command line, use: `tasklist.exe`.  This enables you to filter on a `WINDOWTITLE` attribute as well.  Beyond that, you might be out of luck.

Example to see if an untitled notepad instance is running:

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Notepad"
```

You might use this inside a batch file as follows:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Notepad" ^| find/c "exe"`) DO (
SET windowcount=%%F
)

echo %windowcount%

if "%windowcount%"=="0" (
echo no windows!
) ELSE (
echo %windowcount% windows found!
)
```

Comment: Does the example I added answer your question?  Or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: can you also tell me how to list all open windows

Comment: Sorry, @HcgRandon, I don't know how to list them all from the command line.  Prior to a little while ago, I wasn't even sure how to do what your original question asked for.  Consider checking if Sysinternals (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027) provides such a utility.